# "Parameter is not valid" error when retrieving image

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to retrieve images from a SQL Server database using C#. However, I'm getting the error message

> Parameter is not valid

Please help me.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string q = "select * from Rough where name='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";

     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SMS_DB;Integrated Security=True");

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
     SqlDataReader dr;

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        byte[] img = null;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = (dr["ID"].ToString());
            textBox2.Text = (dr["Name"].ToString());
            textBox3.Text = (dr["Image"].ToString());
            img = (byte[])(dr["Image"]);

            if (img == null)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = null;
            }
            else
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                // ms.Close();
            }
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think there is a mistake in your connection string what is (local) if you use sqllocaldb you must write (localdb)\<instansename>

Comment: at what line are you getting the error?

Comment: I think the error is at that line
textBox3.Text = (dr["Image"].ToString());
I ask why you try to get image at the text box, you only need to put it's name and take the image as a byte.

Comment: My guess would be `img` doesn't represent a valid image for some reason. But we'd need to see the code that saves that image byte array to see if there's a problem with it. Also, read up on SQL injection, you should not build SQL queries like this, you should use a parameter to pass in the value for `comboBox1.Text`.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @MahdyAslamy: `(local)` just denotes a full, local, unnamed SQL Server instance (not LocalDB - SQL Server Developer, Web, Standard, Enterprise editions)